# Deleting Chained Duplicates

Tags: numpy, pandas, duplicates, hdf5

Lets say I have a list:

```
lits = [1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

and i need this to become `[1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0]`
(Delete duplicates, but only in a chain of duplicates. Going to do this on a huge HDF5 file, with pandas, numpy. Would rather not use a for loop iterating through all elements.

```
table = table.drop_duplicates(cols='[SPEED OVER GROUND  [kts]]', take_last=True)
```

Is there a modification I can do to this code?

Comment: Why do you have in the output `[1, 1, ...`. Are they not in a chain? How does this fit your wording?

Comment: I think (based on desired output) he is more literally saying he wants at most one duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In pandas you can do a boolean mask, selecting a row only if it is differs from either the preceding or succeeding value:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({ 'lits':lits })

>>> df[ (df.lits != df.lits.shift(1)) | (df.lits != df.lits.shift(-1)) ]

    lits
0      1
2      1
3      2
4      0
7      0
8      3
9      3
10     1
11     4
12     5
13     2
15     2
16     0
18     0
```